# Unable to login in Odesk Team Room

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, odesk

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I Unable to Login to My O-Desk Team Room. I don't know why or I don't know what happen.

I unable to work and lot's works are pending.

I am using **oDesk Team Linux/3.2.59 Revision: 7744 Build: 1**

Is there any version that work in Ubuntu 14.04?

I remove software and install again but same problem occur.

Please Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Odesk having 2 beta version - Please download last one - New beta having bug that's why. I was having same issue when start tracking.

First completely uninstalled and installed new software.